# Nested macros not looping

Tags: vba, excel

I have a project that keeps growing and growing and growing.  I'm at the last bit and it isn't looping.  I'm not seeing why.  I have the elements in their own macros and they perfectly until I try to combine them into a super macro that runs them all. The idea is that the "master" workbook (XLSM) will run its own update, THEN Open all other XLSM files in the same folder and run THEIR Updates which pushes data to other XLSX files.  Right now each XLSM file runs a macro that works perfectly by 
    Sub EndofDay ()
    Call step 1
    Call Step 2
    End Sub
I used the same "Do while" structure for the SuperMacro that opens the other books and calls their "EndofDay".  it gets through a couple of the XLSM files then stops with an error on MyFiles = Dir. the following syntax SHOULD run the masters updates and one other code string, THEN open all other XLSM files in the Folder.  Why does it suddenly not work at this level when It works on the level under this.

```
Sub SuperMacroEOD_Trans()

    Dim MyFiles As String
        Call EndofDayTransfer 'Do this Workbook Transfer first then:
'Step 2: Specify a target folder/directory.
    MyFiles = Dir("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\*.xlsm")

'Dont try to open this workbook and do anything.
    Do While MyFiles <> "" And MyFiles <> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\Update_Master.xlsm"
'Step 3: Open Workbooks one by one
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\" & MyFiles

    Call EndofDayTransfer 'Call same macro you ran and run in the other workbooks (they contain it).

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Step 4: Next File in the folder/Directory
      Loop
    MyFiles = Dir <------------Gets stuck here or editor turns it yellow.


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few logic mistakes in your code.

1- Here you're telling the code to **stop** when reached the master file, but what you actually want is to **skip** the master file. also you are comparing a simple filename to a fullpath name

> `Do While MyFiles <> "" And MyFiles <> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\Update_Master.xlsm"`

2- This should be put inside the loop, that is, *before* the line `Loop`

> `MyFiles = Dir <------------Gets stuck here or editor turns it yellow.`

3- you are using `ActiveWorkbook` which is pretty hazardous. you should use *explicit* references. Moreover since all the workbooks have the procedure "EndofDayTransfer", including the master WB, it is mandatory to specify explicitly the "scope" so that the appropriate procedure is run (see `Application.Run` in the code below)

```
Sub SuperMacroEOD_Trans()
    Dim MyFiles As String, wb As Workbook
    Call EndofDayTransfer ' Master Workbook Transfer first

    MyFiles = Dir("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\*.xlsm")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
        If MyFiles <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then ' skip the master
            ' Always get an explicit reference to any file you open and use it 
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\QA VBA Project\" & MyFiles)
            Application.Run "'" & wb.name & "'!EndofDayTransfer" ' <-- specify scope explicitly to disambiguate
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If

        MyFiles = Dir ' <-- inside the loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Moving Loop under "MyFiles" creates a compile error and dosen't run anything.

Comment: There must be an error somewhere else. Check the file names and paths again plz.

Comment: Did you test my code as is? Did you replace "ME" by your actual home folder?

Comment: Sorry.  forgot I left loop in the wrong place from previous tinkering.  

converting to the above it still gets stuck on MyFiles = Dir  One of "Master's" clones (analyst workbook.XLSM did not run.  BUT running it manually everything went fine.

I could just Call each one up to run specifically but this would be so much cooler and more dynamic.  This way it isn't necessary to modify the code but just make new or change filenames.

Comment: @ScottH you can eventually add some error handling to avoid that the loop stops if some workbook does not have such a procedure or fails to run it. I am sure that the overall structure of the code is the correct one, you can build on it. :)

Comment: Can syntax INSIDE a called Macro can mess with the called Macro? Oh yes I took your syntax and corrected it for my actual file paths.

Comment: @ScottH certainly not for syntax errors. But the code above surely does not have any syntax error, I guarantee it to you :). It was even tested on my machine, just with different paths and files, with some "dummy" routine `EndofDayTransfer` in each.

Comment: The edited version above works PERFECTLY.  tested several times.  phew!  This test was for thee XLSM to update to 5 XLSX.  Now to make it for real... 7 XLSM updating to 12 XLSX files....tomorrow.

Comment: complete test is running on the shared drive.  7 xlsm workbooks find and open 12 XLSX workbooks and push data to them based on tab names.